# How do you load the default leaderboard prior to 6.0?

Tags: ios, objective-c, game-center, gamekit

When loading the default leaderboard, it seems you have to detect whether the user is running iOS 6.0 or 7.0.

For 7.0, you use [loadDefaultLeaderboardIdentifierWithCompletionHandler](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKLocalPlayer_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/GKLocalPlayer/loadDefaultLeaderboardIdentifierWithCompletionHandler%3a).

For 6.0, you use [loadDefaultLeaderboardCategoryIDWithCompletionHandler](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKLocalPlayer_Ref/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/GKLocalPlayer/loadDefaultLeaderboardCategoryIDWithCompletionHandler%3a).

But what if the user is running 5.0 or even 4.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Back in the iOS 5 days, you didn't retrieve the default category ID. You simply initialized a score with `-[GKScore init]` and the score was submitted to the default category. To retrieve the scores in the default category, you supplied the category ID via `-[GKLeaderboard setCategory:]`.

I'd link to the iOS 5 docs, but I can't find the individual pages online. If you like, you can download the docset [here](http://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/docsets/20120725/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiOS5_1.iOSLibrary.xar). (Unarchive it with [xar](https://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/archivers/xar/Portfile).)